# Фильтрация списка 1 по параметрам из списка 2. Как реализовать фильтрацию?

Tags: java, android

В первом активити пользователь выбирает цвет/цвета, который имеет тот или иной "гаджет". После выбора цвета во 2 активити отобраежается отфильтрованный список "гаджетов", которые подходят под выбранные цвета. При этом цвет гаджета хранится в описании в webview 3 активити. Описание гаджета хранится в файле тхт в ресурсах.

1 активити

```
 public class Filter_activity extends Activity implements 
 View.OnClickListener {
 ListView Filtering;
 String[] Filter;


 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter_activity);

 Filtering = findViewById(R.id.Filtering);

 Filtering.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
 this, R.array.Filter,
 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice);
 Filtering.setAdapter(adapter);

 Button button_2 = findViewById(R.id.button_2);
 button_2.setOnClickListener(this);

 Filter = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Filter);
 }


 public void onClick(View v) {
 switch (v.getId()) {
 case R.id.button_2:
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Filter_activity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
 break;

 }
 }
```

2 активити

```
 public class Gadgets_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
 ListView Gadget_list;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_gadgets_activity);

 Gadget_list = findViewById(R.id.Gadget_list);

 String[] Gadget = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Gadget);

 ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this, 
 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Gadget);

 Gadget_list.setAdapter(adapter);

 Gadget_list.setOnItemClickListener
 (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setClass(Gadgets_activity.this, Discription_activity.class);
 intent.putExtra("title", position);
 startActivity(intent);
 }
 });
 }
 }
```

3 активити

```
 public class Discription_activity extends AppCompatActivity {


 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_discription_activity);

 WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView_1);

 Intent intent = getIntent();

 String resName = "n" + intent.getIntExtra("title", 0);
 Log.i("name", resName);
 Context context = getBaseContext(); 


 String text = readRawTextFile(context, 
 getResources().getIdentifier(resName,
 "raw", "Shop_application"));

 webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, "text/html", "en_US", null);
 }

 private String readRawTextFile(Context context, int resId)
 {
 InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

 InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

 BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
 String line;
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

 try {
 while (( line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
 builder.append(line);
 builder.append("\n");
 }


 } catch (IOException e) {
 return null;
 }
 return builder.toString();
 }

 }
```

Comment: и в чем вопрос?

Comment: Как отфильтровать список 1 по параметрам из списка 2 ?